# Asp.net MVC multiple fields in dropdown list failing to postback to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list that shows the Code & BudgetCodename of db.Budgets from the database.

the view snippet looks like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-btns">
                        <a href="" class="minimize">&minus;</a>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="panel-title">Block Styled Form</h4>
                    <p>This is an example of form with block styled label.</p>
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                               @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BudgetCodeID, "BudgetCode:", new { @class = "control-label" })
                               @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BudgetCodeID, (SelectList)ViewBag.BudgetsList, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BudgetCodeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                   </div>

}
```

and the controller looks like this:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {


            var Budgets = (from m in db.BudgetCodes
             select new SelectListItem {
              Text = m.Code + "| " + m.BudgetCodeName,
              Value = m.BudgetCodeID.ToString()
          });

        ViewBag.BudgetsList = new SelectList(Budgets, "Value", "Text");

}
```

The drop down menu looks fine, and shows both thE Code and BudgetCodeName.

But the box does not post back the data to the sql Database. No errors are created.

What could I have done wrong ?

****Edit****

I have tried placing the controller text as such, but it doesn't work:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "ClinicalAssetID,AssetTypeID,ProductID,ManufacturerID,ModelID,SupplierID,SerialNo,PurchaseDate,PoNo,Costing,TeamID,StaffID,WarrantyEndDate,InspectionDate,InspectionOutcome,InspectionDocumnets,InspectionDueDate,BudgetCodeID")] ClinicalAsset clinicalAsset)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.ClinicalAssets.Add(clinicalAsset);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.AssetTypeID = new SelectList(db.AssetTypes, "AssetTypeID", "AssetTypeName", clinicalAsset.AssetTypeID);
            ViewBag.ProductID = new SelectList(db.Products, "ProductID", "ProductName", clinicalAsset.ProductID);
            ViewBag.ModelID = new SelectList(db.Models, "ModelID", "ModelName", clinicalAsset.ModelID);
            ViewBag.ManufacturerID = new SelectList(db.Manufacturers, "ManufacturerID", "ManufacturerName", clinicalAsset.ManufacturerID);
            ViewBag.SupplierID = new SelectList(db.Suppliers, "SupplierID", "SupplierName", clinicalAsset.SupplierID);
            ViewBag.TeamID = new SelectList(db.Teams, "TeamID", "TeamName", clinicalAsset.TeamID);
            ViewBag.StaffID = new SelectList(db.Staffs, "StaffID", "StaffName", clinicalAsset.StaffID);
            ViewBag.InspectionOutcomeID = new SelectList(db.InspectionOutcomes, "InspectionOutcomeID", "InspectionOutcomeResult", clinicalAsset.InspectionOutcomeID);
            var Budgets = (from m in db.BudgetCodes
                           select new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Text = m.Code + " | " + m.BudgetCodeName,
                               Value = m.BudgetCodeID.ToString()
                           });
            ViewBag.BudgetsList = new SelectList(Budgets, "Value", "Text");
            return View(clinicalAsset);
        }
```

****Update****

I have found that removing the async from the controller does post back the integer to the table. How do I then make it work with async ? or is it worth dropping async altogether if i don't expect heavy loads or bandwidth issues because of a small user base ?

```````
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ClinicalAssetID,AssetTypeID,ProductID,ManufacturerID,ModelID,SupplierID,SerialNo,PurchaseDate,PoNo,Costing,TeamID,StaffID,WarrantyEndDate,InspectionDate,InspectionOutcome,InspectionDocumnets,InspectionDueDate, BudgetCodeID")] ClinicalAsset clinicalAsset)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.ClinicalAssets.Add(clinicalAsset);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.AssetTypeID = new SelectList(db.AssetTypes, "AssetTypeID", "AssetTypeName", clinicalAsset.AssetTypeID);
            ViewBag.ProductID = new SelectList(db.Products, "ProductID", "ProductName", clinicalAsset.ProductID);
            ViewBag.ModelID = new SelectList(db.Models, "ModelID", "ModelName", clinicalAsset.ModelID);
            ViewBag.ManufacturerID = new SelectList(db.Manufacturers, "ManufacturerID", "ManufacturerName", clinicalAsset.ManufacturerID);
            ViewBag.SupplierID = new SelectList(db.Suppliers, "SupplierID", "SupplierName", clinicalAsset.SupplierID);
            ViewBag.TeamID = new SelectList(db.Teams, "TeamID", "TeamName", clinicalAsset.TeamID);
            ViewBag.StaffID = new SelectList(db.Staffs, "StaffID", "StaffName", clinicalAsset.StaffID);
            ViewBag.InspectionOutcomeID = new SelectList(db.InspectionOutcomes, "InspectionOutcomeID", "InspectionOutcomeResult", clinicalAsset.InspectionOutcomeID);
            var Budgets = (from m in db.BudgetCodes
                           select new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Text = m.Code + " | " + m.BudgetCodeName,
                               Value = m.BudgetCodeID.ToString()
                           });
            ViewBag.BudgetsList = new SelectList(Budgets, "Value", "Text");
            return View(clinicalAsset);
        }

``````
```````

Comment: when you submit the form, is the action hit? can you put a debug breakpoint in your POST Create action to verify?

Comment: @johnluke.laue I have found that removing the async from the controller does post back the integer to the table. How do I then make it work with async ? or is it worth dropping async altogether if i don't expect heavy loads or bandwidth issues because of a small user base ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that removing the async from the controller does post back the integer to the table.

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ClinicalAssetID,AssetTypeID,ProductID,ManufacturerID,ModelID,SupplierID,SerialNo,PurchaseDate,PoNo,Costing,TeamID,StaffID,WarrantyEndDate,InspectionDate,InspectionOutcome,InspectionDocumnets,InspectionDueDate, BudgetCodeID")] ClinicalAsset clinicalAsset)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.ClinicalAssets.Add(clinicalAsset);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.AssetTypeID = new SelectList(db.AssetTypes, "AssetTypeID", "AssetTypeName", clinicalAsset.AssetTypeID);
            ViewBag.ProductID = new SelectList(db.Products, "ProductID", "ProductName", clinicalAsset.ProductID);
            ViewBag.ModelID = new SelectList(db.Models, "ModelID", "ModelName", clinicalAsset.ModelID);
            ViewBag.ManufacturerID = new SelectList(db.Manufacturers, "ManufacturerID", "ManufacturerName", clinicalAsset.ManufacturerID);
            ViewBag.SupplierID = new SelectList(db.Suppliers, "SupplierID", "SupplierName", clinicalAsset.SupplierID);
            ViewBag.TeamID = new SelectList(db.Teams, "TeamID", "TeamName", clinicalAsset.TeamID);
            ViewBag.StaffID = new SelectList(db.Staffs, "StaffID", "StaffName", clinicalAsset.StaffID);
            ViewBag.InspectionOutcomeID = new SelectList(db.InspectionOutcomes, "InspectionOutcomeID", "InspectionOutcomeResult", clinicalAsset.InspectionOutcomeID);
            var Budgets = (from m in db.BudgetCodes
                           select new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Text = m.Code + " | " + m.BudgetCodeName,
                               Value = m.BudgetCodeID.ToString()
                           });
            ViewBag.BudgetsList = new SelectList(Budgets, "Value", "Text");
            return View(clinicalAsset);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the data you want to POST into a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "YOUR CONTROLLER", FormMethod.Post)) {    
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BudgetCodeID, "BudgetCode:", new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BudgetCodeID, (SelectList)ViewBag.BudgetsList, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BudgetCodeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
}
```

Your POST action needs to accept the model you are posting:

```
public ActionResult Post(MyModel model)
{
     //call a service to save info to database
}
```

Comment: Please see my Updated Post

Answer (score 0):

In your code. The data you are sending in a action method is of type POST.

```
   [HttpPost]
```

[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task Create()

You have to define the "FormMethod" in your view page. For example:

@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionMethod Name", "Controller Name", FormMethod.Post))
    {

}
`
I hope this my help.

Comment: no, because im using @model Assets.Areas.Clinical.Models.ClinicalAsset. all other fields post back just fine